# "Expected an indented block" error while coding python for discord bot

Tags: python, bots, discord

I am getting some errors with my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online")


@client.command()
async def raid(ctx):
while True:
await ctx.send("""@Raider come show some support and join the raid!
Meet: (link1)
Target: (link2)
Raid Call: """)
await asyncio.sleep(5)




client.run("token")
```

When I run the code I get:

[image]

Comment: Please include both your code and the errors in the question. Also, please keep the question plain and only what is relevant to your problem.

Comment: indent whats after `while True:`

Comment: Fixed, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's this section:

```
async def raid(ctx):
while True:
await ctx.send("""@Raider come show some support and join the raid!
Meet: (link1)
Target: (link2)
Raid Call: """)
await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Just needs to be indented properly:

```
async def raid(ctx):
    while True:
        await ctx.send("""@Raider come show some support and join the raid!
        Meet: (link1)
        Target: (link2)
        Raid Call: """)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

After declaring the function `def raid(ctx):` the block below needs to be indented.  Then for the conditional `while True:` *it's* block needs to be indented as well.

If you are looking to get into Python, I'd suggest this course, it's free and pretty fun:

https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python

Comment: Make sure to answer relevant question in the future. This will most likely be closed soon enough. If you really want to help OP even if its question will be close, write a comment.

Comment: Still getting error.

Comment: The same error?

Comment: Yes, same error.

Comment: I've updated the answer, try it again.  If you get an error take note of the line number

Comment: OK, thank you for your help and suggesting that course. I will definitely check it out.